# Windows Phone menu animation in CSS3

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to achive an animation like windows phone on this video at 3:02 you can see the animation:

http://youtu.be/E7a0QwubpUI?t=3m2s

this the animations keyframe:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateNavLeftIn {
from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-15%) scale(.4) rotateY(100deg);
    transform: translateX(-15%) scale(.4) rotateY(100deg);

}
to { 

}}


@keyframes rotateLeftOut {
from { }
to { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8) translate3d(-25%,-10%,0) rotateY(-90deg); 
    opacity:0;
}}
```

this my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aboutluca/f0f4n6dr/

As you can see is not bad but is no like the real one. What could I do to improve it?

Thank you

Comment: I think it's pretty close. By the looks of it, you should fade out the first item a little quicker while keeping the animation more or less the same. The incoming item needs to start a little later, so the items don't appear over each other.

Comment: thank you, much better with the second slide opacity from 0 and some delay!